# Can an email address be used for a UML package namespace

Tags: uml

Is there a standard for naming packages in UML?

Answer (score 1):

Not as such.  There is a convention that follows the Java package naming standards, e.g. `com.yourcompany.yourapp.yourlib.yadda.yadda.yadda`.  UML packages are more about the logical separation of functionality/responsibility than their name structure.